How do I use php to add custom properties to docx
I am trying to prepare a docx template file with pre-inserted custom properties (Quick Part -> Fields) from a database.  The file starts as an empty docx file created in MS Word.
I reviewed this question
But it does not answer my question.
My code is as follows:
$blank_DOCX_template = DATAPATH."formletter_blank_templates/blank.docx";
        
$zip = new \ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($blank_DOCX_template) == true) {
    $updatedXmlContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties" xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">';
    $id_num = 2;
    foreach($properties as $prop_name=>$prop_val){
         $updatedXmlContent .= '<property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="'.$id_num.'" name="'.$prop_name.'"><vt:lpwstr>'.$prop_val.'</vt:lpwstr></property>';
         $id_num++;
    }
    $updatedXmlContent .= '</Properties>';

    $zip->addFromString('docProps/custom.xml', $updatedXmlContent);
    $zip->close();

}else{
    echo "could not open file";
}

Once the code has run (it produces no errors), I can look into the zip file 'docProps/custom.xml' and every thing looks right.  The xml file exists and has the same content as a file with the same properties manually inserted through the MS Word interface, but when I open the file in MS Word the custom properties inserted from my php code do not appear.
What am I missing?

You could try to start with an "empty" docx file that already has a custom.xml in it. There is probably a link somewhere to that xml file that you're missing when you start with a truely empty docx file. To be honest, I don't really know if such a distinction exists.... but it's an idea.

You are a genius!! I created a MSWord docx that had one custom property.  Then my code worked.  I guess the docProp/custom.xml had to already exist.  Thank you.

Ah, it worked. Nice.  Yes, the link to the custom.xml probably doesn't exist in the main document when it's not there. It does make sense.

@MatthewInboden can you write up the solution as an answer so others can be helped by it. You can even mark your own answer as accepted.

The properties under QuickParts are special Content Controls and only partly connected to document properties; not at all connected to custom document properties. Also, not connected to fields. See https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/EnhancedDocProp_AddIn.html.
